# zsh git command auto-complete add extra origin to the git branch name

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, git

After I clone a git repository locally, I want to switch branch to, says, 'ABCD'.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/ABCD
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

$ git checkout origin/ABCD   #### <- Here is the problem!
Note: checking out 'origin/ABCD'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at f2bf54a... Clean up README.md
```

When I press tab after `git checkout`, for some reason the autocompletion always starts with `origin/` and hence a warning message of **detached HEAD** state.

How can I make the autocomplete **not** to add 'origin' at the beginning?

Comment: I don't see a completion issue here: you don't have a local branch `ABCD`, so it's normal for zsh to offer only `master` and `origin/…` as completions. Why did you expect other completions? To create a local branch, run `git checkout -t origin/ABCD` or `git branch -t ABCD origin/ABCD`.

Comment: If I switch to bash and tried `git checkout <TAB>` I will see ABCD instead even though ABCD is not a no local branch. I think it is a behavioural difference.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This annoys me too and means I need to either manually type the branch or go back and delete the `origin` part. Are we doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Also stuck. Currently, the only option seems to be to just type out the full name. A bit of a pain, compared to bash behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a great plugin for `zsh` that you can use. If you are using `oh-my-zsh` then its called `gitfast` or if just using `zsh` then you can follow the instructions on his blog article.

As the author details there are in fact quite a lot of `git` completion issues and his efforts are to resolve them all. This is one issue that now works like the way it does in bash.

https://felipec.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/how-i-fixed-git-zsh-completion/

To enable in `oh-my-zsh` edit your `.zshrc` and change the plugins line to add gitfast like so

```
plugins=(git gitfast)
```

Comment: If someone finds a non-plugin solution, please add!